24S Lifepo4 battery draining
I built a 24s lifepo4 battery for my golf cart. I’m having an issue where under load cell 2 drops voltage while all others barely drop. Is this indicative of a bad cell? Or a poor connection? Any help is appreciated. 

Cell 02 shows a wire resistance nearly double that of the others, that would tend to suggest a poor connection.

Ok thank you was hoping it was bad connection.

There is something wrong with the tool, 0.077 x 40 A = 3V drop, so the cell should show something like 0.6V, not 2.5V. What kind of cell do you have to get 40A discharge rate?
